# Distribute processes to cores

Tags: bash

I am trying to minimize the run-time of a program as much as possible which is handled by "master" bash script I wrote.

My way of parallelizing the process (since is fully-parallelizable) is the following

```
for((i=0;i<${max_processes};i++)) ; do

    echo "Creating child with arg ${i}"
    bash _spawn.sh ${i} &
done 

wait
```

The _spawn.sh script does something with the passed argument.

While waiting I observed the `htop` log and I was not completely sure that this is the correct way to parallelize the procedure (although the CPU time is smaller now).

Can I do this in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU parallel:

```
max_processes=100
parallel bash _spawn.sh ::: $(seq 1 $max_processes)
```

This will run as many parallel processes that you have CPU cores at the same time

Check https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

---

To figure out how it run, N*CPU cores at a time, you can test it:

```
parallel 'sleep 1; echo arg {1}' ::: {0..100}
```

### Output:

```
arg 0
arg 1
arg 2
arg 3
arg 4
arg 5
arg 6
arg 7
```

So I have 8 CPU cores and 8 // processes at a time

Comment: After testing your suggestion with the ```parallel``` tool and my implementation I found out that the execution time is just the same as before over multiple iterations. So I guess,  what I did is not actually that far off. 

I was unaware of the gnu ```parallel``` though. Thank you!

Comment: The `sleep` trick does not work if you have > 100 cores. `parallel --number-of-threads` should work, though (or `parallel --number-of-cores` if you want number of actual cores).