# How can I view the output of multiple bg processes?

Tags: bash

*This is a follow-up question to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1247232/distribute-processes-to-cores/1247328#1247328). But since, they are not related I created another question.*

So, in this scenario, I am running multiple background processes in order to speed up my program execution time. This is working fine. The CPU-time of the whole execution is now to a minimum value.

But, I would like to see some output from the background processes. The **master script** that is currently being run is something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
total_procs=10
for ((i=0;i<$total_procs;i++)); do
    echo "[MASTER]: Spawning child ${i}."
    bash _spawn.sh ${i} &
done
wait #for the processes to end
```

For the sake of simplicity lets just say that **_spawn.sh** script does something trivial like:

```
#!/bin/bash
my_arg=${1}
echo "[${my_arg}     ]: Hi, I am child #${my_arg}!
```

The output on the terminal the master script gets called now looks like this:

```
[MASTER]: Spawning child 0.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 1.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 2.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 3.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 4.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 5.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 6.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 7.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 8.
[MASTER]: Spawning child 9.
```

But, what I would like to see, is this (although the 'parallel' processes are in the background):

```
[MASTER]: Spawning child 0.
[0     ]: Hi, I am child #0!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 1.
[1     ]: Hi, I am child #1!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 2.
[2     ]: Hi, I am child #2!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 3.
[3     ]: Hi, I am child #3!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 4.
[4     ]: Hi, I am child #4!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 5.
[5     ]: Hi, I am child #5!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 6.
[6     ]: Hi, I am child #6!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 7.
[7     ]: Hi, I am child #7!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 8.
[8     ]: Hi, I am child #8!
[MASTER]: Spawning child 9.
[9     ]: Hi, I am child #9!
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: If a fractional delay is not a problem for you , you can add "sleep 0.01 " after the line "bash _spawn.sh ${i} &" . I've tested your script with a 0.01 second delay for spawning the new process and that worked as you expected.

Comment: Looks like spawning a new process is far more time-consuming than running a for loop in bash. I tested your script with 100 processes to spawn instead of just 10 , and guess what ? After spawning the 11th proc , the output "[0     ]: Hi, I am child #0!" got appeared. LOL :)

Comment: @ParsaMousavi I only need a small amount of processes which of course are in number smaller than the amount of my available CPU cores.  I was wondering if there is a trick that one can do with redirecting I/O streams to the terminal that has the master process.

Comment: I tried [I/O redirection with a new file descriptor](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/r7ZVRF64Ss/) , but it has the same problem as in your post . The best way that came into my mind was to use the sleep command because forking processes are slower than running a for loop.